# dplyr Exclude row

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for an dplyr equivalent on

```
SELECT user_id, item 
  FROM users
  WHERE user_id NOT IN (1, 5, 6, 7, 11, 17, 18); -- admin accounts
```

I can use 
`users %>% filter(user_id != 1)` but can't imagine using multiple `&&` all the way.

Is there a way to exclude a number of rows?

Comment: `%in%` is a function in R.

Comment: You could also [create a `%notin%` function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5831829/496488).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `!` and `%in%`:

```
filtered_users <- filter(users, !user_id %in% c(1, 5, 6, 7, 11, 17, 18))
```

This is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444336/1152809. I just googled "dplyr not in" and this was the first result. Google is your friend when learning new things. Also, as @thelatemail said, [`%in%`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) is a base R function.